# ggplot shape codes to hexadecimal

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes, kable

I have few data on a ggplot and on a table (type of kable) and I want to add a column on the kable with the same shapes I have on the ggplot, like the table below,

```
some_symbols <- c('\u25A0', '\u25B3','\u25CF','\u2605')
```

(I found the hex codes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp))

```
data.frame(
  Symbol =some_symbols,
  Description = rep("bla bla bla", 4),
  Result = rep("bla bla", 4)
) %>%
  mutate(
    Symbol = cell_spec(Symbol, escape = F)
  ) %>%
  kable(escape = F, align = c("c", "l", "l")) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
```

[image]

However, I want to use the same symbols I have on my ggplot and *avoid* setting shapes on my own

```
p_trial <- mtcars[1:5, ] %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = hp, shape = interaction(vs, am), colour = interaction(vs, am))) +
  geom_point(size = 7)
```

[image]

From the function `ggplot_build(p_trial)$data[[1]]` I can get the shape code but I cannot use it as input in my table as it's not a hexadecimal code.

[image]

At the same time, the colour from the above output is in convenient format and I can use it directly to modify the colour by doing

```
    data.frame(
      Symbol =some_symbols,
      Description = rep("bla bla bla", 4),
      Result = rep("bla bla", 4)
    ) %>%
      mutate(
        Symbol = cell_spec(Symbol,
     color = ggplot_build(p_trial )$data[[1]] %>% pull(colour),
 escape = F)
      )
```

My question is, how can I turn ggplot shape codes to hexadecimal code or
how can I put in a table(type of kable) a column  with the same shapes used in ggplot?

Thanks

Comment: Why not specify the shapes you want in ggplot? `shape` can take a single character as an argument, so passing your unicode escapes to `scale_shape_manual(values = c('\u25A0', '\u25B3','\u25CF','\u2605'))` might do the trick.

Comment: Or add the unicode-shapes to the data frame and use `scale_shape_identity()`.

Comment: I've tried that way but it doesn't work well because the table has the same "shape" on different rows and I have to assign the proper "shape" per row.  Also I don't want to spend time in choosing shapes manually

Comment: The problem is that the standard plotting symbols used in R are not text glyphs - they are graphics primitives drawn onto the plotting device as circles, rectangles, polygons etc. If you are trying to replicate them in a table, you need a table onto which R can draw graphics primitives. In a kable this can be done with `spec_plot`, though it would likely be difficult to implement a single symbol. An alternative would be to use ggplot itself to generate a nice table instead.

Comment: If you don't mind the effort of finding unicode equivalents to the 26 base R plot symbols, you could use a named vector `unicode_lookup <- (1 = '\uXXXX', 2 = '\uXXXX', ...)` and look up the matching unicode character with `unicode_lookup[as.character(n)]` where `n` is the shape number you pull from the `ggplot_build` info. *Note the `as.character` so as not to index the lookup vector by position.*